# Cheerio how to remove DOM elements from selection

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

I am trying to write a bot to convert a bunch of HTML pages to markdown, in order to import them as Jekyll document. For this, I use `puppeteer` to get the HTML document, and `cheerio` to manipulate it.

The source HTML is pretty complex, and polluted with Google ADS tags, external scripts, etc. What I need to do, is to get the HTML content of a predefined selector, and then remove elements that match a predefined set of selectors from it in order to get a plain HTML with just the text and convert it to markdown.

Assume the source html is something like this:

```html
<html>
<head />
<body>
<article class="post">
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<script>That for some reason has been put here</script>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>
<ins>Google ADS</ins>
<p>Third paragraph.</p>
<div class="related">A block full of HTML and text</div>
<p>Forth paragraph.</p>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to achieve is something like

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>
<p>Third paragraph.</p>
<p>Forth paragraph.</p>
```

I defined an array of selectors that I want to strip from the source object:

```js
stripFromText: ['.social-share', 'script', '.adv-in', '.postinfo', '.postauthor', '.widget', '.related', 'img', 'p:empty', 'div:empty', 'section:empty', 'ins'],
```

And wrote the following function:

```js
const getHTMLContent = async ($, selector) => {
  let value;
  try {
    let content = await $(selector);
    for (const s of SELECTORS.stripFromText) {
      // 1
      content = await content.remove(s);
      // 2
      // await content.remove(s);
      // 3
      // content = await content.find(s).remove();
      // 4
      // await content.find(s).remove();
      // 5
      // const matches = await content.find(s);
      // for (m of matches) {
      //  await m.remove();
      // }
    };
    value = content.html();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(`- [!] Unable to get ${selector}`);
  }
  console.log(value);
  return value;
};
```

Where

- `$` is the cheerio object containing `const $ = await cheerio.load(html);`
- `selector` is the dome selector for the container (in the example above it would be `.post`)

What I am unable to do, is to use cheerio to `remove()` the objects. I tried all the 5 versions I left commented in the code, but without success. Cheerio's documentation didn't help so far, and I just found this [link](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/416) but the proposed solution did not work for me.

I was wondering if someone more experienced with cheerio could point me in the right direction, or explain me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a classical newby error in my code, I was missing an `await` before the `.remove()` call.

The working function now looks like this, and works:

```js
const getHTMLContent = async ($, selector) => {
  let value;
  try {
    let content = await $(selector);
    for (const s of SELECTORS.stripFromText) {
      console.log(`--- Stripping ${s}`);
      await content.find(s).remove();
    };
    value = await content.html();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(`- [!] Unable to get ${selector}`);
  }
  return value;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the elements with `remove`:

```
$('script,ins,div').remove()
```